# Is glib command line parsing order-sensitive?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, glib, fastq

Is glib's command line option parsing order sensitive? In the code below, I define option `--foo` before `--bar` in the `GOptionEntry` array. parsing `--foo --bar` sets both to true, but with `--bar --foo` only `foo` to true.  How do I make it disregard order, since unordered options are the norm in *nix afaik.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <glib.h>

static bool foo = false;
static bool bar = false;

static GOptionEntry entries[] =
{
  { "foo" , 0 , 0 , G_OPTION_ARG_NONE , &foo , "foo" , NULL } ,
  { "bar" , 0 , 0 , G_OPTION_ARG_NONE , &bar , "bar" , NULL } ,
  { NULL }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    GError * error = NULL;
    GOptionContext * context = g_option_context_new ("- convert fastq");
    g_option_context_add_main_entries (context, entries, NULL);

    if (!g_option_context_parse (context, &argc, &argv, &error)){
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s\n", foo ? "foo is true" : "foo is false");
    printf("%d\n", bar ? "bar is true" : "bar is false");
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
> ./test2 
foo is false
bar is false
> ./test2 --foo
foo is true
bar is false
> ./test2 --foo --bar
foo is true
bar is true
> ./test2 --bar
foo is false
bar is true
> ./test2 --bar --foo
foo is true
bar is false
```

Comment: Not having used GOptionContext I can't say what you're doing wrong... but I'll challenge your assertion that *nix options are unordered. When they don't _conflict_, obviously, the order may not matter -- but when they do, or when they're intermixed with other arguments, order definitely _does_ matter for some commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arg_data` pointer in the`GOptionEntry` struct should point to a `gboolean`, not a `bool`. A `gboolean` is the same size as a `gint`, which is probably larger than a `bool`. In your last test, settimg `foo` probably overwrites `bar`.

Comment: That was exactly the issue.  I seriously would've never thought of it, thank you.